# Quick question... Vines?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you grow vines? I'm trying to make them grow without blocks behind them. When ever I try, they never grow, or if I do place blocks behind them and destroy the blocks so the vines are still there, they get destroyed too...
I'm try to make a rim of vines along a bed room, but it won't work!

Comment: What game are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about Minecraft Pocket Edition, v.013.1alpha

Comment: I'd recommend you use the proper tags. They're important for proper organization and makes sure we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

in minecraft pe, you cannot grow vines by yourself. You either need a tree, and the vines grow there, or you can mine them with shears and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

if you place a vine on a floating block it will grow to the ground but if you destroy that block all the vines will disappear. I use creative and have a bridge with vines growing to the water but it takes lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

Vines need to be supported on a wall to grow. this means the block you place the vine on can't be broken. otherwise you will break the vine.

Leave the highest block that the vine is placed on to make it grow